# Understanding and implementing the OAuth2 Authorisation Server

Tags: database, oauth-2.0, pkce

I'm trying to implement the backend for an oAuth2 architecture to allow authorisation of a mobile application.  The best practice seems to be to use `PKCE` with an `authorization code` flow.  This mitigates the risk of storing a `client_secret` on the application itself.

I've been looking at this diagram for reference:

[image]

- There seems to be plenty of examples on the web showing the db for an `Auth0
  tenant`, but doesn't seem to be much incorporating the PKCE `Code
  Challenge` and `Code Verifier`.  How are the `Code Challenge` ,`Code
  Verifier` and `Authorisation Code` all interlinked and how are they
  verified on the `Auth0 Tenant` in stage 8 on the diagram?
- This leads onto my next question about designing a relational database to hold this information.  A user trying to claim authorisation on the Auth0 Tenant will only have one `Code Challenge` sent at a time, so could this information be held in a user table?  I've been looking at this [script](https://github.com/tegaphilip/padlock/blob/master/app/db/padlock.sql) for ideas.
- In terms of designing this, what are the advantages of separating out
  the `Auth0 Tenant server` from the `authentication server`?  I plan
  to implement the Auth0 Tenant for authentication the app (I own it in
  this sense).

In the future, I plan to incorporate other social media `Auth0 Tenants` as authentication.

**References:**

- https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/auth-code-pkce
- https://auth0.com/docs/flows/guides/auth-code-pkce/add-login-auth-code-pkce

Answer (score 0):

Authorization Servers are provided by cloud providers who deal with this complexity + many other non functional requirements.

I would focus on your UIs and APIs instead - there is more than enough complexity already - see my write up on the challenges involved in a simple mobile app: https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/